# GWT Window Redirection to Another Page

Tags: gwt

Hi I have this code in my Sencha gXt app which purpose is to change when user click on login button then show another page as  follows:

```
String url = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "MyApplicationFrame.html";
Window.Location.replace(url);
```

It's Redirecting but in MyApplicationFrame.html showing same login page. I have another class with frames. I want to show the control of that class.

### MyApplicationFrame.html

```
enter code here
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="MyFirstGXT.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="gxt/css/gxt-all.css">
    <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="myfirstgxt/myfirstgxt.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript enabled -->
    <noscript>
      <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
        Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
        in order for this application to display correctly.
      </div>
    </noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a problem in MyApplicationFrame.html.

Comment: MyApplicationFrame.html look like above

Comment: So, is `myfirstgxt` the module that you want to redirect to? If it is, then there is a problem in the authentication call - authentication fails and your user is still presented with a login page.